# iOS Standalone HTML5 App 'click' event not firing on dynamically injected input

Tags: jquery, ios, html, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm encountering an issue which seems to occur only in standalone mode of a HTML5 app which I saved to the **Home** screen of my iOS device.

By standalone mode, I mean a HTML web app with the following `metatag`:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

The javascript (written in coffeescript) in question is the following:

```
$( ->
  $(document).on('click', 'input', (e) ->
    alert('click')
  )

  $(document).on('focusout', 'input', (e) ->
    alert('blur')
  )
)
```

These are delegated event handlers to handle dynamically injected `<input>` elements. The `alert()` messages show up fine in Mobile Safari. However, when the web app is viewed in standalone mode (i.e., launched from the **Home** screen), the events do not fire.

I'm using jQuery v1.10.2 if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar issue where dynamically created inputs don't have a cursor or allow you to type in them when you click/touch the input for the first time. The keyboard comes up, and the page scrolls which makes it appear that the input is selected, but in fact, it's not. A second touch/click in the input puts the cursor in the input, and allows text to be inputted.

My workaround was to attach a touchend event to that particular input, and then focus that input again programmatically using jQuery's focus(). I had to use touchend because the click event wouldn't fire in standalone mode.

Below is a code snippet, you'll have to excuse the syntax, I'm using Backbone. This is the method called on touchend of my input.

```
clickedInput: function (e) {

    if (window.navigator.standalone) {

        $(e.currentTarget).focus();

    }

}
```